# find entry of a collection by multiple keys

Tags: java, collections

How can I store data in java, so that I can access it by any of the stored fields, without having to store the data multiple times?

lets assume I have got a class like this:

```
class Fruit {
    String name;
    String Color;
    int count;
    //...
}
```

and then I have got a few instances of that class:

```
Fruit f1 = ("banana","yellow",4);
Fruit f2 = ("apple","red",2);
Fruit f3 = ("tomato","red",4);
//...
```

now is there any way to store that data, so that I not only get the fruit by their name, but for example also get all fruits that are yellow. or all fruits with the count 4?

I also already thought of using `java.util.List` in combination with `Stream.filter();` but I am pretty sure there are some third-party-libraries out there, which are faster. I just wasn´t able to find any.

Comment: Maybe something like `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap`?

Comment: Why not use streams and then worry about "faster" when your code is written.

Comment: *It doesn't seem to match your requirements at all.* @StephenC what makes you say that?

Comment: Well ... `BeanMap` provides a way to view a single instance of a bean as a `Map`; i.e. exposing the fields of that instance via `get(name)` and `set(name, value)` methods.  But the OP's requirements (as I read them) are to be able to query a *collection* of beans; e.g. "get all fruits that are yellow".

Comment: You can also conside Map in this case. color will be the key and you can use Array to store names of your fruit. It's easier to fetch all the fruit having same color and even the size.

Comment: Covered by `BeanMap` or `List<BeanMap>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupByEach` from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) to group an item by multiple keys.

```
record Fruit(String name, String color, int count) {}

@Test
public void groupFruitByNameAndColorAndCount()
{
    Fruit f1 = new Fruit("banana", "yellow", 4);
    Fruit f2 = new Fruit("apple", "red", 2);
    Fruit f3 = new Fruit("tomato", "red", 4);
    MutableList<Fruit> fruit = Lists.mutable.of(f1, f2, f3);

    ListMultimap<Object, Fruit> index =
        fruit.groupByEach(each -> List.of(each.name, each.color, each.count));

    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f1), index.get("banana"));
    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f2), index.get("apple"));
    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f3), index.get("tomato"));
    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f1), index.get("yellow"));
    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f2, f3), index.get("red"));
    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f1, f3), index.get(4));
    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f2), index.get(2));
}
```

Because the keys are different types, `String` (name), `String` (color) and `Integer` (count), the type of the key in the `ListMultimap` has to be `Object`.

I would normally recommend using multiple `groupBy` calls to index data by different types.

```
ListMultimap<String, Fruit> fruitByName = fruit.groupBy(Fruit::name);
ListMultimap<String, Fruit> fruitByColor = fruit.groupBy(Fruit::color);
ListMultimap<Integer, Fruit> fruitByCount = fruit.groupBy(Fruit::count);
```

In both cases, there will be references to the same `Fruit` instances stored in multiple Lists. The data itself will not be copied, just the references.

It is possible to iterate over the fruit once and update three Multimap indices using a combination of `asLazy`, `tap` and `forEach`.

```
MutableListMultimap<String, Fruit> byName = Multimaps.mutable.list.empty();
MutableListMultimap<String, Fruit> byColor = Multimaps.mutable.list.empty();
MutableListMultimap<Integer, Fruit> byCount = Multimaps.mutable.list.empty();
fruit.asLazy()
        .tap(each -> byName.put(each.name, each))
        .tap(each -> byColor.put(each.color, each))
        .forEach(each -> byCount.put(each.count, each));

Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f1), byName.get("banana"));
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f2, f3), byColor.get("red"));
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f1, f3), byCount.get(4));
```

If you don't want to create an index for lookups, and don't mind the cost of multiple iterations of the fruit `List`, then you could just use Java `Stream` to `filter` the data you want.

```
List<Fruit> bananaList = fruit.stream()
        .filter(each -> "banana".equals(each.name))
        .toList();
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f1), bananaList);

List<Fruit> redList = fruit.stream()
        .filter(each -> "red".equals(each.color))
        .toList();
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(f2, f3), redList);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Comment: This helped me a lot. In my actual scenario (which was rather complicated, therefore I do not want to get into the details), I had some data stored that should be accessible by a class and a String. With a few changes in the code, I managed to get it to work, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

> *"How can I store data in java, so that I can access it by any of the stored fields, without having to store the data multiple times? ..."*

I don't believe there is any inherent way to do this in Java.

Although, you won't have to store it multiple times to achieve the effect.

If there is an abstraction, it would most-likely be part of the *[Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/package-summary.html#JavaCollectionsFramework)* framework.
Here is the link to the *JavaDoc*, if you'd like to review the available interfaces.
*[Collections Framework Overview (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/doc-files/coll-overview.html)*.

> *"... is there any way to store that data, so that I not only get the fruit by their name, but for example also get all fruits that are yellow. or all fruits with the count 4? ..."*

I recommend just creating a separate method, for each look-up.

You can utilize the *ArrayList* to store the data.
These will return a list of matches, considering there may be more than one result—or *null*, when no match is found.

```java
List<Fruit> findName(String string, List<Fruit> list) {
    List<Fruit> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Fruit fruit : list) {
        if (fruit.name.equals(string)) results.add(fruit);
    }
    return results.size() == 0 ? null : results;
}

List<Fruit> findColor(String string, List<Fruit> list) {
    List<Fruit> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Fruit fruit : list) {
        if (fruit.Color.equals(string)) results.add(fruit);
    }
    return results.size() == 0 ? null : results;
}

List<Fruit> findCount(int value, List<Fruit> list) {
    List<Fruit> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Fruit fruit : list) {
        if (fruit.count == value) results.add(fruit);
    }
    return results.size() == 0 ? null : results;
}
```

And, here is an example.

```java
Fruit f1 = new Fruit("banana","yellow",4);
Fruit f2 = new Fruit("apple","red",2);
Fruit f3 = new Fruit("tomato","red",4);

List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(f1, f2, f3));

System.out.println(findName("apple", list));
System.out.println(findColor("red", list));
System.out.println(findCount(4, list));
```

Output

```
[apple]
[apple, tomato]
[banana, tomato]
```